# Cannot find methods about binding Qt-Designer4 with Python

Tags: python, qt

I'm  tired about looking for the methods to deal with widgets within python class (Python 2.7 & PyQt4) who load file.ui (GUI QTDesigner)

**CODE**

```
form_class = uic.loadUiType("MyPythonProgram.ui")[0]

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):

def __init__(self, parent = None):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.btn_buscar.clicked.connect(self.buscar)

def addingResultsToQListView(self):
    for item in SomeList:
        self.listView.addItem(item) ###It's not correct, but cannot find the right one

def onListItemClicked():
    getItem = listView.currentItem().text() ###It's not correct, but cannot find the right one

def buscar(self):
    getEditText = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
    ### Don't know how to do this function. I want to get the edittext to search on some website and retrieve the results into a list. then the list will be added to QlistView (just found C++ methods, not for python)
    #Finally        
    getEditText = '' ###After click on 'btn_buscar', want to clear this field 

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
MyWindow = MyWindowClass(None)
MyWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

It could be helper to get some DOC, or some help about making python apps hybrid (Android if its possible), keeping .ui and .py layers separately as I'm trying to show you.

This is my .ui for more information:

[image: UI QT DESIGNER4]

QUESTION'
How could I bind python functions with elements on .ui? I was trying too much methods but didn't find the right one. Need to know how to deal with QlistView and Qedittext... Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry, updated, though that was clear the question, I commented what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I do it: separate the classes between construction (loading) of the UI and changing its content.

```
form_class = uic.loadUiType("MyPythonProgram.ui")[0]

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QMainWindow, form_class):   
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class myGui:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gui = MyWindowClass() # that's the trick!
        # self.addindResultsToQListView() # doesn't work, because I don't have your list items
        self.gui.btn_buscar.clicked.connect(self.buscar)
        self.editText = None

    def show(self):
        self.gui.show()

    def addingResultsToQListView(self):
        for item in SomeList: # you need to specify this `list` before this works!
            self.gui.listView.addItems(item) 

    def buscar(self):
        self.editText = self.gui.textEdit.text()
        self.gui.textEdit.setText("") 

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
MyWindow = MyGui()
MyWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

The trick is to reference the `MyWindowClass`, which is the constructor of your gui and hence the GUI itself, as an object within the class that controls the content of your GUI (`myGui`).

You call `myGui` on toplevel which then calls `MyWindowClass` as the object `self.gui`. From then on, whenever you want to address something in your GUI you name it `self.gui.` and add the QObject.

I also tried to understand what you want to do for the `pushBotton`. The content of your TextEdit (in PyQt they are called `lineEdit` btw) is stored in the variable `self.editText` which is initialized as `None`. Afterwards, the `lineEdit` is cleared from the user content.

Comment: Cannot do anything with QListView... can you help me please? other stuff was correct! Now im in a trouble: self.gui.listView.addItem(item) 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addItem'

Comment: I think the function is called `addItems` (plural), so I changed that in my code! Unfortunately I don't have the possibility to check that code (missing .ui file). My focus was on your initial question of how to structure the code to get it start the GUI. Hope the update helps though.

Comment: Are you sure the widget is named `listView`?

Comment: Yes, let me update this question with .ui, thanks ;)

Comment: Excuse me, i'd like to know how to deal with QLCDNumber using my code, because I initialize self.variable_QLCDnumber = None and when I want to display any number, get error because cannot do display on NoneType item... please

Comment: Cannot help you without the code, I'm afraid. You might want to consider open a new question or edit the code in this one.

Comment: Nevermind, finally got it!     self.gui.lcd.display(len(lista))     always are self.gui.... thanks anyway ;)